# Swift - Having issues getting multiple network calls back in the order they were given using gcd

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift and decided to build a simple weather app. I'm having a problem getting the weather data back in the order I asked for it. 
In my view controller I have 2 properties, weatherData and locations which are both arrays. When the app is opened, I load all the saved locations from UserDefaults. Then, I iterate through each location and make multiple network calls to receive the weather data for each location. I'm using dispatch groups to make sure I wait until all data has been loaded before I use the weather data to load viewModels that use it. The problem is that the weatherData is not always returned in the same order I asked for it so the location and weatherData indices are not aligned / synced. I thought that using DispatchQueue.main.async would be serial and would execute the items in order but this doesn't seem to be happening. I obviously am not correctly understanding how gcd is working and am really struggling to find a solution to this. Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Code in viewController

```
private func updateWeatherData() {
    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()


    for i in 0..<locations.count {
        myGroup.enter()
        print("Calling fetch Weather for index: ", i )
        self.apiService.fetchWeatherData(for: self.locations[i].location) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Unable to retrieve weather data
                self.presentAlert()
            } else if let response = response {
                print("Finished Request: \(i)")
                self.weatherData.append(response)

            }
            myGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Finished All requests")
        self.locationsTableViewController.viewModel = LocationsViewModel(locations: self.locations, weatherData: self.weatherData)
    }
}
```

Code in my apiService class

```
func fetchWeatherData(for location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping WeatherDataCompletion) {
        // Weather request used to return valid api url string based on location 
        let weatherRequest = WeatherRequest(baseUrl: APIConfiguration.authenticatedBaseUrl, location: location)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherRequest.url) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.didFetchWeatherData(data: data, response: response, error: error, completion: completion)

            }
        }.resume()
    }


    // Error checks and decodes network data response
    private func didFetchWeatherData(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?, completion: WeatherDataCompletion) {
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, .failedRequest)
            print("No WeatherData Available: ", error)
        } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    // Decode JSON
                    let weatherData = try decoder.decode(DarkSkyResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(weatherData, nil)
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to Decode JSON: ", error)
                    completion(nil, .invalidResponse)
                }
            } else {
                print("Status Code: ", response.statusCode)
                completion(nil, .failedRequest)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil, .unknown)
        }
    }
```

EDIT: As the answer mentioned, I've learned URLSession doesn't guarantee order. I ended up just saving each result by index in the initial loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherRequest.url)
```

there is no guarantee that you'll receive the responses for the requests in order , so you may create a model that contains the request with some number property , then after all responses finish here

```
myGroup.notify(queue: .main) { }
```

sort them according to the number or do this

```
class LocationsViewModel {
   var loc:CLLocation
   var weatherData:DarkSkyResponse?
   init(loca:CLLocation) {
     self.loc = loca
   } 
   func fetchWeatherData(completion: @escaping WeatherDataCompletion) {
    // here do the fetch and assign the weatherData
     weatherData = decodeRes 

   }
}
```

another thing also is you can chain the requests in a way that after a response returns make the next call and so on , also you should remove

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
```

as everything should happen in the background thread